# Search IP /24 network in dict of ISPs

Tags: python, ip-address

I have an IP Address which I would like to replace after the 3rd dot. e.g.
IP

```
156.13.216.251
```

Output:

```
156.13.216.0
```

With this output I would like like to be able to search a dictionary to match the result:

IPList =

```
[
'156.13.216.251'
'156.13.216.250'
]
```

Dict:

```
 {
            "techCountry": "ISP",
            "techCity": "saint-petersburg",
            "techName": "Cahit Eyigunlu",
            "adminState": "pr.",
            "registrantPostalCode": "e16 1ah",
            "telephone": "+443333031000",
            "domain": "156.13.216.0"
}
```

As the output matches I would like to then append this to a new dict with the matched result.

I have attempted to split it on the first three with the following but it appears to split it all:

```
for i in IPList:
    i.split(".",3)[:3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a library named [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html).

You may easily use it like so:

```
import ipaddress

ip_list = [
'156.13.216.251',
'156.13.216.250'
]

isps = [
     {
        "techCountry": "ISP",
        "techCity": "saint-petersburg",
        "techName": "Cahit Eyigunlu",
        "adminState": "pr.",
        "registrantPostalCode": "e16 1ah",
        "telephone": "+443333031000",
        "domain": "156.13.216.0"
    }
]

# First, I suggest to map the networks to ISPs, otherwise it'll be an O(n) operation
# for every IP.
# We add the /24 to signal a network.
network_to_isp = {isp["domain"] + "/24": isp for isp in isps}


ips_not_found = []
ips_to_isps = {}

for ip in ip_list:
    network = ipaddress.IPv4Network((ip, 24), strict=False)
    isp = network_to_isp.get(str(network))
    if isp is None:
        ips_not_found.append(ip)
    else:
        ips_to_isps[ip] = isp
```

---

Assuming we don't know the network and wish to search, the following code will work.

Keep in mind it might make up to 32 searches per IPv4. Since we don't know the network that the IP exists in. We have no way to circumvent it.

```
import ipaddress

ip_list = [
'156.13.216.251',
'156.13.216.250'
]

isps = [
     {
        "techCountry": "ISP",
        "techCity": "saint-petersburg",
        "techName": "Cahit Eyigunlu",
        "adminState": "pr.",
        "registrantPostalCode": "e16 1ah",
        "telephone": "+443333031000",
        "domain": "156.13.216.0"
    }
]

# First, I suggest to map the networks to ISPs, otherwise it'll be an O(n) operation
# for every IP.
# We assume the network is unknown.
network_to_isp = {ipaddress.ip_address(isp["domain"]): isp for isp in isps}

def iter_supernets(address, *, max_mask=None, min_mask=0):
    network = ipaddress.ip_network(address)
    return (network.supernet(new_prefix=mask)
            for mask in range(max_mask or network.prefixlen, min_mask, -1))

ips_to_isps = {}

for ip in ip_list:
    for network in iter_supernets(ip):
        isp = network_to_isp.get(network.network_address)
        if isp:
            ips_to_isps[ip] = isp
            break
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("No ISP found for {}".format(ip))
```

Comment: I like this approach. 1 question though. How would this work with for example the domain was 45.11.76.0 but the IP address was 45.11.79.9 could i take this back to 45.11?

Comment: @Will The question is what is the network's mask. If it's `/22`, `45.11.79.9` is inside `45.11.76.0/22`. It's not inside `45.11.76.0/24`.  Your data does not include the netmask so I've put a default `/24`. According to your data it is impossible to tell.

Comment: @will added the option to check all subnets.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `Regular Expressions` to split it on third dot (`match pattern`).

```
regex = \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.
```

Example:

If you have ip address `156.13.216.251` then, regex will find `156.13.216.`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of dictionaries, you can iterate over `IPList`and dictionaries in `dct_list` and check if the domains match.

```
out = [dom for dom in IPList for dct in dct_list if '.'.join(dom.split('.')[:3]) in dct['domain']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string built in method also

```
ip[0: ip.rfind('.')] + ".123"
```

The rfind method finds occurrence of character from end of string and provides with index of it